# Removing rows when column has same value, and relating those rows to the same primary key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-delete

I'm working on a project with MySQL 5.7 that deals with a movies database. I have the following tables (that I am not allowed to change):

```
CREATE TABLE `movies` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `director` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `genres` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `genres_in_movies` (
  `genre_id` int NOT NULL,
  `movie_id` int NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (`genre_id`) REFERENCES `genres`(`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`movie_id`) REFERENCES `movies`(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I had records that had to be updated to reflect some valid `genres`. Unfortunately now I have a bunch of duplicate `genres.name` even though the `genres.id` differs. What I would like to do is consolidate all equivalent `genres.name` into a single `genres.id` and `genres.name`. For example, if I have this table:

```
genres (old)
==================
id  |  name      |
==================
2   | Romance    |
------------------
6   | Romance    |
------------------
45  | Romance    |
==================
```

I want to only end up with a single entry where `genres.id = 2` and `genres.name = 'Romance'`.

I could do this easily with the following query:

```
DELETE FROM genres
WHERE genres.id NOT IN (SELECT * 
                       FROM (SELECT MIN(g.id)
                             FROM genres g
                             GROUP BY g.name) 
                       x);
```

but I also want to be able to update `genres_in_movies.genre_id` to reflect the `genres.id` change so that the `movies` table doesn't break. So how can I update the `genres_in_movies` table as well?

Answer (score 1):

First update `genres_in_movies`:

```
update genres_in_movies gin join
       genres g
       on gin.genre_id = g.id join
       (select g2.name, min(g2.id) as minid
        from genres g2
        group by g2.name
       ) g2
       on g2.name = g.name and g2.minid <> g.id
    set gin.genre_id = g2.minid;
```

Then do the delete.

BTW, you can rephrase the `DELETE` using `LEFT JOIN`:

```
DELETE g
    FROM genres g LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT MIN(g.id) as minid
          FROM genres g
          GROUP BY g.name
         ) gmin
         ON g.id = gmin.minid
    WHERE gmin.minid IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Unfortunately, the first update does not work. I get `ERROR: 1054, Unknown column 'g2.name' in 'on clause'`